# Getting the http request when using compojure.route/not-found in Clojure

Tags: clojure, compojure

I'm building a server using Cloujre's Compojure. The default route is `compojure.route/not-found`, is there a way of getting the request that reached this route? I'd like print all requests that end up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this kinda approach:

```
(def handler (-> your-routes
                 wrap-my-request-middleware ;; it has to be in this order
                 ...))
```

Let's log in here the uri

```
(defn wrap-my-request-middleware
  [handler]
  (fn [request]
    (let [response   (handler request)]
      (when (= 404 (:status response))
        ;; do whatever you like in here
        (log/info (str "Request path: " (:uri request))))
      response)));; fn needs to return reponse...
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it also makes the entire server send a 500 error

Comment: @shakedzy this approach looks legit; what is the content of your 500 error?

Comment: I get this: HTTP ERROR: 500

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Response map is nil
Powered by Jetty:// - the logging does occurs, but still..

Comment: I've edited the answer so the code will work - this handler needs to be the last (as it calls the handlers before it) and it has to return `response`, which is what caused the 500 issue

Comment: it was for demonstration you need to return response in any case